# Stored Procedures_errors

Tags: oracle

I have a SQL query which was converted to a stored procedure. I don't find any errors with the syntax but when running this SP, Im getting the errors. But when the SQL is run separately there are no errors and query executes fine.

There is no input variable as it queries the tables using sysdate. Below is the SP and the errors Im getting. Your help is resolving this is highly appreciated.

```
create or replace procedure cs_daily_report
as 
begin
-- SQL to Gather Daily Statistics for Lockbox Cases by Site, Product Type,
-- and Inquiries/Errors
-- When prompted for days_prior enter the number of days prior to the current
-- date that you want the statistics for.
SELECT a.rpt_date report_date,
  a.site,
  a.prod_type,
  a.inq_err,
  opened,
  reopened,
  duplicate,
  resolved,
  resolved_timely
FROM
  -- There are a group of 4 selectes unioned together for each column
  --  (Opened, Reopened, Duplicate, Resolved, and Resolved_Timely).These unioned
  --  results are joined together along with a query to provide the report date
  --  and provide a row for any site + product type + Inquiries/Errors
  --  combination that has no statistics.
  --
  -- The groups of 4 selects unioned together are for:
  --   - WHOLESALE and CUSTOM Inquiries
  --   - WHOLESALE and CUSTOM Errors
  --   - RETAIL Inquiries
  --   - RETAIL Errors
  (((((
  ( -- Selects for date and to pick up every site/product/category.
  SELECT DISTINCT TRUNC(sysdate - 1) rpt_date,
    lbxsite site,
    'WHOLESALE/CUSTOM' prod_type,
    'Inquiries' inq_err
  FROM qt06u_mel.qt_lbxcurpoint
  WHERE lbxprodtype IN ('CUSTOM', 'WHOLESALE')
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT TRUNC(sysdate - 1) rpt_date,
    lbxsite site,
    'WHOLESALE/CUSTOM' prod_type,
    'Errors' inq_err
  FROM QT06U_mel.qt_lbxcurpoint
  WHERE lbxprodtype IN ('CUSTOM', 'WHOLESALE')
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT TRUNC(sysdate - 1) rpt_date,
    lbxsite site,
    'RETAIL' prod_type,
    'Inquiries' inq_err
  FROM QT06U_mel.qt_lbxcurpoint
  WHERE lbxprodtype = 'RETAIL'
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT TRUNC(sysdate - 1) rpt_date,
    lbxsite site,
    'RETAIL' prod_type,
    'Errors' inq_err
  FROM QT06U_mel.qt_lbxcurpoint
  WHERE lbxprodtype = 'RETAIL'
  ) a
LEFT JOIN
  -- Selects for Opened.
  (
  SELECT lbxsite SITE,
    'WHOLESALE/CUSTOM' PROD_TYPE,
    'Inquiries' Inq_Err,
    COUNT(*) Opened
  FROM PRPC_71SDS.pclb_work
  WHERE lbxprodtype IN ('CUSTOM', 'WHOLESALE')
    -- Created on the date specified.
  AND TRUNC(pxcreatedatetime) = TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
    -- Not an Error
  AND ((worktypecode != 'FRN'
  AND iserror         = 'No')
  OR (worktypecode    = 'FRN'
  AND errorsource    != 'Remittance Processing'))
  GROUP BY lbxsite
  UNION
  SELECT lbxsite SITE,
    'WHOLESALE/CUSTOM' PROD_TYPE,
    'Errors' Inq_Err,
    COUNT(*) Opened
  FROM PRPC_71SDS.pclb_work
  WHERE lbxprodtype                          IN ('CUSTOM', 'WHOLESALE')
  AND TRUNC(pxcreatedatetime) = TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
  AND ((worktypecode         != 'FRN'
  AND iserror                 = 'Yes')
  OR (worktypecode            = 'FRN'
  AND errorsource             = 'Remittance Processing'))
  GROUP BY lbxsite
  UNION
  SELECT lbxsite SITE,
    'RETAIL' PROD_TYPE,
    'Inquiries' Inq_Err,
    COUNT(*) Opened
  FROM PRPC_71SDS.pclb_work
  WHERE lbxprodtype           = 'RETAIL'
  AND TRUNC(pxcreatedatetime) = TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
    -- Is an Error
  AND ((worktypecode != 'FRN'
  AND iserror         = 'No')
  OR (worktypecode    = 'FRN'
  AND errorsource    != 'Remittance Processing'))
  GROUP BY lbxsite
  UNION
  SELECT lbxsite SITE,
    'RETAIL' PROD_TYPE,
    'Errors' Inq_Err,
    COUNT(*) Opened
  FROM PRPC_71SDS.pclb_work
  WHERE lbxprodtype           = 'RETAIL'
  AND TRUNC(pxcreatedatetime) = TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
  AND ((worktypecode         != 'FRN'
  AND iserror                 = 'Yes')
  OR (worktypecode            = 'FRN'
  AND errorsource             = 'Remittance Processing'))
  GROUP BY lbxsite
  ) b
ON a.site       = b.site
AND a.prod_type = b.prod_type
AND a.inq_err   = b.inq_err)
LEFT JOIN
  ( -- Selects for Reopened
  SELECT lbxsite SITE,
    'WHOLESALE/CUSTOM' PROD_TYPE,
    'Inquiries' Inq_Err,
    COUNT(*) Reopened
  FROM PRPC_71SDS.pclb_work
  WHERE lbxprodtype IN ('CUSTOM', 'WHOLESALE')
    -- Created in the past year.
  AND pxcreatedatetime >= TRUNC(sysdate - interval '1' YEAR - interval '1' DAY)
  AND ((worktypecode   != 'FRN'
  AND iserror           = 'No')
  OR (worktypecode      = 'FRN'
  AND errorsource      != 'Remittance Processing'))
    -- Reopened on the date specified and was not opened on the same date.
  AND TRUNC(pyreopentimestamp)  = TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
  AND TRUNC(pyreopentimestamp) != TRUNC(pxcreatedatetime)
  GROUP BY lbxsite
  UNION
  SELECT lbxsite SITE,
    'WHOLESALE/CUSTOM' PROD_TYPE,
    'Errors' Inq_Err,
    COUNT(*) Reopened
  FROM PRPC_71SDS.pclb_work
  WHERE lbxprodtype            IN ('CUSTOM', 'WHOLESALE')
  AND pxcreatedatetime         >= TRUNC(sysdate - interval '1' YEAR - interval '1' DAY)
  AND ((worktypecode           != 'FRN'
  AND iserror                   = 'Yes')
  OR (worktypecode              = 'FRN'
  AND errorsource               = 'Remittance Processing'))
  AND TRUNC(pyreopentimestamp)  = TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
  AND TRUNC(pyreopentimestamp) != TRUNC(pxcreatedatetime)
  GROUP BY lbxsite
  UNION
  SELECT lbxsite SITE,
    'RETAIL' PROD_TYPE,
    'Inquiries' Inq_Err,
    COUNT(*) Reopened
  FROM PRPC_71SDS.pclb_work
  WHERE lbxprodtype             = 'RETAIL'
  AND pxcreatedatetime         >= TRUNC(sysdate - interval '1' YEAR - interval '1' DAY)
  AND ((worktypecode           != 'FRN'
  AND iserror                   = 'No')
  OR (worktypecode              = 'FRN'
  AND errorsource              != 'Remittance Processing'))
  AND pyreopentimestamp         = TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
  AND TRUNC(pyreopentimestamp) != TRUNC(pxcreatedatetime)
  GROUP BY lbxsite
  UNION
  SELECT lbxsite SITE,
    'RETAIL' PROD_TYPE,
    'Errors' Inq_Err,
    COUNT(*) Reopened
  FROM PRPC_71SDS.pclb_work
  WHERE lbxprodtype             = 'RETAIL'
  AND pxcreatedatetime         >= TRUNC(sysdate - interval '1' YEAR - interval '1' DAY)
  AND ((worktypecode           != 'FRN'
  AND iserror                   = 'Yes')
  OR (worktypecode              = 'FRN'
  AND errorsource               = 'Remittance Processing'))
  AND TRUNC(pyreopentimestamp)  = TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
  AND TRUNC(pyreopentimestamp) != TRUNC(pxcreatedatetime)
  GROUP BY lbxsite
  ) c
ON a.site       = c.site
AND a.prod_type = c.prod_type
AND a.inq_err   = c.inq_err)
LEFT JOIN
  ( -- Selects for Duplicate
  SELECT lbxsite SITE,
    'WHOLESALE/CUSTOM' PROD_TYPE,
    'Inquiries' Inq_Err,
    COUNT(*) Duplicate
  FROM PRPC_71SDS.pclb_work
  WHERE lbxprodtype                    IN ('CUSTOM', 'WHOLESALE')
  AND pxcreatedatetime >= TRUNC(sysdate - interval '1' YEAR- interval '1' DAY)
  AND ((worktypecode   != 'FRN'
  AND iserror           = 'No')
  OR (worktypecode      = 'FRN'
  AND errorsource      != 'Remittance Processing'))
    -- Is a duplicate resolved on the specified date.
  AND TRUNC(pyresolvedtimestamp) = TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
  AND pystatuswork               = 'Resolved-Duplicate'
  GROUP BY lbxsite
  UNION
  SELECT lbxsite SITE,
    'WHOLESALE/CUSTOM' PROD_TYPE,
    'Errors' Inq_Err,
    COUNT(*) Duplicate
  FROM PRPC_71SDS.pclb_work
  WHERE lbxprodtype             IN ('CUSTOM', 'WHOLESALE')
  AND pxcreatedatetime          >= TRUNC(sysdate - interval '1' YEAR - interval '1' DAY)
  AND ((worktypecode            != 'FRN'
  AND iserror                    = 'Yes')
  OR (worktypecode               = 'FRN'
  AND errorsource                = 'Remittance Processing'))
  AND TRUNC(pyresolvedtimestamp) = TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
  AND pystatuswork               = 'Resolved-Duplicate'
  GROUP BY lbxsite
  UNION
  SELECT lbxsite SITE,
    'RETAIL' PROD_TYPE,
    'Inquiries' Inq_Err,
    COUNT(*) Duplicate
  FROM PRPC_71SDS.pclb_work
  WHERE lbxprodtype              = 'RETAIL'
  AND pxcreatedatetime          >= TRUNC(sysdate - interval '1' YEAR- interval '1' DAY)
  AND ((worktypecode            != 'FRN'
  AND iserror                    = 'No')
  OR (worktypecode               = 'FRN'
  AND errorsource               != 'Remittance Processing'))
  AND TRUNC(pyresolvedtimestamp) = TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
  AND pystatuswork               = 'Resolved-Duplicate'
  GROUP BY lbxsite
  UNION
  SELECT lbxsite SITE,
    'RETAIL' PROD_TYPE,
    'Errors' Inq_Err,
    COUNT(*) Duplicate
  FROM PRPC_71SDS.pclb_work
  WHERE lbxprodtype              = 'RETAIL'
  AND pxcreatedatetime          >= TRUNC(sysdate - interval '1' YEAR - interval '1' DAY)
  AND ((worktypecode            != 'FRN'
  AND iserror                    = 'Yes')
  OR (worktypecode               = 'FRN'
  AND errorsource                = 'Remittance Processing'))
  AND TRUNC(pyresolvedtimestamp) = TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
  AND pystatuswork               = 'Resolved-Duplicate'
  GROUP BY lbxsite
  ) d
ON a.site       = d.site
AND a.prod_type = d.prod_type
AND a.inq_err   = d.inq_err)
LEFT JOIN
  ( -- Selects for Resolved
  SELECT lbxsite SITE,
    'WHOLESALE/CUSTOM' PROD_TYPE,
    'Inquiries' Inq_Err,
    COUNT(*) Resolved
  FROM PRPC_71SDS.pclb_work
  WHERE lbxprodtype                    IN ('CUSTOM', 'WHOLESALE')
  AND pxcreatedatetime >= TRUNC(sysdate - interval '1' YEAR + interval '1' DAY)
  AND ((worktypecode   != 'FRN'
  AND iserror           = 'No')
  OR (worktypecode      = 'FRN'
  AND errorsource      != 'Remittance Processing'))
    -- Resolved on the date specified and is not a duplicate.
  AND TRUNC(pyresolvedtimestamp) = TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
  AND pystatuswork              != 'Resolved-Duplicate'
  GROUP BY lbxsite
  UNION
  SELECT lbxsite SITE,
    'WHOLESALE/CUSTOM' PROD_TYPE,
    'Errors' Inq_Err,
    COUNT(*) Resolved
  FROM PRPC_71SDS.pclb_work
  WHERE lbxprodtype             IN ('CUSTOM', 'WHOLESALE')
  AND pxcreatedatetime          >= TRUNC(sysdate - interval '1' YEAR + interval '1' DAY)
  AND ((worktypecode            != 'FRN'
  AND iserror                    = 'Yes')
  OR (worktypecode               = 'FRN'
  AND errorsource                = 'Remittance Processing'))
  AND TRUNC(pyresolvedtimestamp) = TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
  AND pystatuswork              != 'Resolved-Duplicate'
  GROUP BY lbxsite
  UNION
  SELECT lbxsite SITE,
    'RETAIL' PROD_TYPE,
    'Inquiries' Inq_Err,
    COUNT(*) Resolved
  FROM PRPC_71SDS.pclb_work
  WHERE lbxprodtype              = 'RETAIL'
  AND pxcreatedatetime          >= TRUNC(sysdate - interval '1' YEAR + interval '1' DAY)
  AND ((worktypecode            != 'FRN'
  AND iserror                    = 'No')
  OR (worktypecode               = 'FRN'
  AND errorsource               != 'Remittance Processing'))
  AND TRUNC(pyresolvedtimestamp) = TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
  AND pystatuswork              != 'Resolved-Duplicate'
  GROUP BY lbxsite
  UNION
  SELECT lbxsite SITE,
    'RETAIL' PROD_TYPE,
    'Errors' Inq_Err,
    COUNT(*) Resolved
  FROM PRPC_71SDS.pclb_work
  WHERE lbxprodtype              = 'RETAIL'
  AND pxcreatedatetime          >= TRUNC(sysdate - interval '1' YEAR + interval '1' DAY)
  AND ((worktypecode            != 'FRN'
  AND iserror                    = 'Yes')
  OR (worktypecode               = 'FRN'
  AND errorsource                = 'Remittance Processing'))
  AND TRUNC(pyresolvedtimestamp) = TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
  AND pystatuswork              != 'Resolved-Duplicate'
  GROUP BY lbxsite
  ) e
ON a.site       = e.site
AND a.prod_type = e.prod_type
AND a.inq_err   = e.inq_err)
LEFT JOIN
  ( -- Selects for Resolved Timely
  SELECT lbxsite SITE,
    'WHOLESALE/CUSTOM' PROD_TYPE,
    'Inquiries' Inq_Err,
    COUNT(*) Resolved_Timely
  FROM PRPC_71SDS.pclb_work
  WHERE lbxprodtype                    IN ('CUSTOM', 'WHOLESALE')
  AND pxcreatedatetime >= TRUNC(sysdate - interval '1' YEAR - interval '1' DAY)
  AND ((worktypecode   != 'FRN'
  AND iserror           = 'No')
  OR (worktypecode      = 'FRN'
  AND errorsource      != 'Remittance Processing'))
    -- Resolved on the date specified, is not a duplicate, and is timely.
  AND TRUNC(pyresolvedtimestamp) = TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
  AND pystatuswork              != 'Resolved-Duplicate'
  AND timely                     = 'T'
  GROUP BY lbxsite
  UNION
  SELECT lbxsite SITE,
    'WHOLESALE/CUSTOM' PROD_TYPE,
    'Errors' Inq_Err,
    COUNT(*) Resolved_Timely
  FROM PRPC_71SDS.pclb_work
  WHERE lbxprodtype             IN ('CUSTOM', 'WHOLESALE')
  AND pxcreatedatetime          >= TRUNC(sysdate - interval '1' YEAR - interval '1' DAY)
  AND ((worktypecode            != 'FRN'
  AND iserror                    = 'Yes')
  OR (worktypecode               = 'FRN'
  AND errorsource                = 'Remittance Processing'))
  AND TRUNC(pyresolvedtimestamp) = TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
  AND pystatuswork              != 'Resolved-Duplicate'
  AND timely                     = 'T'
  GROUP BY lbxsite
  UNION
  SELECT lbxsite SITE,
    'RETAIL' PROD_TYPE,
    'Inquiries' Inq_Err,
    COUNT(*) Resolved_Timely
  FROM PRPC_71SDS.pclb_work
  WHERE lbxprodtype              = 'RETAIL'
  AND pxcreatedatetime          >= TRUNC(sysdate - interval '1' YEAR - interval '1' DAY)
  AND ((worktypecode            != 'FRN'
  AND iserror                    = 'No')
  OR (worktypecode               = 'FRN'
  AND errorsource               != 'Remittance Processing'))
  AND TRUNC(pyresolvedtimestamp) = TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
  AND pystatuswork              != 'Resolved-Duplicate'
  AND timely                     = 'T'
  GROUP BY lbxsite
  UNION
  SELECT lbxsite SITE,
    'RETAIL' PROD_TYPE,
    'Errors' Inq_Err,
    COUNT(*) Resolved_Timely
  FROM PRPC_71SDS.pclb_work
  WHERE lbxprodtype              = 'RETAIL'
  AND pxcreatedatetime          >= TRUNC(sysdate - interval '1' YEAR - interval '1' DAY)
  AND ((worktypecode            != 'FRN'
  AND iserror                    = 'Yes')
  OR (worktypecode               = 'FRN'
  AND errorsource                = 'Remittance Processing'))
  AND TRUNC(pyresolvedtimestamp) = TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
  AND pystatuswork              != 'Resolved-Duplicate'
  AND timely                     = 'T'
  GROUP BY lbxsite
  ) f
ON a.site       = f.site
AND a.prod_type = f.prod_type
AND a.inq_err   = f.inq_err)
ORDER BY a.SITE,
  a.PROD_TYPE,
  a.INQ_ERR DESC
  end cs_daily_report;
```

Error Details:
Project: sqldev.temp:/IdeConnections%23iQtrack_QA.jpr
iQtrack Dev Admin

```
Error(8,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(392,3): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
Error(392,22): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge
```

Comment: maybe **/** at the end is needed

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after the final `DESC`, before `end cs_daily_report;`. What are you doing with the query results though? You aren't selecting *into* anything, or opening a cursor. You seem to have you just stuck a begin/end around an existing query, rather than adapting it for a PL/SQL context.

Comment: I just export the query results to an excel and send to the group who needs this report. Do I need to add cursors for converting it to a SP?